# Homebrew - requested URL retuned error: 404

Tags: homebrew

I am trying to installed an older version of terragrunt using brew.
I have `cd`'d into the tap directory of `homebrew-core`, found the commit I needed and attempted to install the version.

However I am getting the following error:

```
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/terraform/manifests/0.13.2
##O=#  #
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
Error: Failed to download resource "terraform_bottle_manifest"
Download failed: https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/terraform/manifests/0.13.2
```

if I try to access the URL manually (through the browser) I get the following error message:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required"}]}
```

Is there anything I am able to do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:

Homebrew provides versiond formula `terraform@0.13`. (`terraform`, `terraform@0.13` are different formulae, installed into different locations.)

```
brew install terraform@0.13
```

---

`https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core` is the `HOMEBREW_BOTTLE_DOMAIN`, where all the prebuilt binary releases (bottles) are cached.

The error you provided means the cached prebuilt is deleted. (I guess Homebrew only provided bottles for the latest formulae.) You need to build `terraform` from source by yourself.

```
brew install --build-from-source terraform
```